# Have you told him?/Did you tell him?

Tags: tense, idiomatic-language

A: I already know what's going to happen.

B: You do? (to C) Have you told him?/Did you tell him?

C: No, I haven't said a word.

Are "have you told him?" and "Did you tell him?" equally natural here?

Comment: Both are perfectly idiomatic and both are commonly used

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They're equally natural. *Have you told him* treats the telling as an act which continues to have relevance to now, *did you tell him* treats it as a completed act. Both forms are available in most cases.